# Facebook sdk, logout when site reloads

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, sdk, logout

I am new to the Facebook javascript SDK.
In the last hours i learned how to make a login with facebook on my webpage.

```
function login() {
        FB.login();
    }
```

I also made a logout button.

```
function logout(){
   FB.logout(function(response) {
   });
 }
```

the buttons are working.
The problem what i am facing now is, when i successfully login and i reload the page, i am automatically logged out. How to keep the user logged in?
I want the user only to logout if he clicks on the button logout.

Comment: You to either use localStorage (check browser support) to save user data or re-fetch it after checking user status using [`FB.getLoginStatus`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus)

Comment: thx. I have checked out the FB.getLoginStatus. When i restart it says that i am not logged in. But if i put the FB.login() in one of the if sentences, then it can log the user in again. But this keeps opening a new window on every page...